# Fork load capacity

Tags: fork, carbon

I saw that the carbon fork of a bike has load capacity of 9 kg. Isn't it way too little? I assume my weight (and that of cargo) does not spread evenly 50/50 on front and back wheels but still, say the total load is 100 kg, what load does it exercise on the fork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fork load is related to the additional load the fork can take. For example strapping tents/sleeping bags/gear to it for bikepacking.

The normal load from the rider is normally given through max rider weight. Altough I have never seen this given for a fork as it highly depends on the geometry of the bike.

Comment: Thank you! (I thought directly linking to a product is forbidden?)

Comment: Where did I put a direct link?

Comment: Not you, me. "Altough I have never seen this given for a fork" I thought you are saying that if I included a link, you could be more specific.

Comment: @EcirHana It's OK to link a product as long as your goal isn't to advertise that product. It doesn't sounds like you're advertising, to me.

Comment: Ah ok now I now what you mean. Well you could link it for clarifications.